# Warning on installing CUTORCH about missing dependency files that are there

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, lua

I am trying to install cuda, torch, cutorch and cudnn on Ubuntu. Cuda and Torch are installed by when I attempt to do luarocks install cutorch. I get a ton of errors. Primarily a stream of this:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindCUDA/make2cmake.cmake:65 (message):
Removing non-existent dependency file: generic/THTensorCopy.h
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindCUDA/make2cmake.cmake:65 (message):
Removing non-existent dependency file: generic/THTensorMath.h
```

The file actually does exist:

```
$locate THTensorCopy.h

~/torch/install/include/TH/generic/THTensorCopy.h
~/torch/pkg/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorCopy.h
```

Is there a way around this to get cutorch installed?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this:

```
luarocks install FindCUDA
```

then reinstall cutorch and cunn.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem installing Torch on Cuda 9.0 and 9.2. Solved it with:

```
export TORCH_NVCC_FLAGS="-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__"
```

before running `./install.sh`